# how to change the particular marker color in angular maps

Tags: typescript, angular-google-maps

I have 5 markers displaying on the map, I want to change only one marker color, I am using angular google maps how can I do that.

I have used the [iconUrl] to change color of the markers, but it is changing all the colors but I want to change only one color of the marker

HTML:

```
              <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [fitBounds]="true" >
                <agm-marker [iconUrl]="iconUrl" *ngFor="let data of map_dev"   [latitude]="data.latitude" [longitude]="data.longitude"
                         [agmFitBounds]="true" (markerClick)="markerdata(data)" >
                </agm-marker>
              </agm-map>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What did you try to get unstuck? Please, show your efforts! [so] is not a code-writing service, it is a repository of high-quality knowledge for the entire world of programming.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - This is no longer relevant since the author changed the whole description.

---

The formula is (based on my first google result when searching for "kelvin to fahrenheit")
`(Kelvin − 273.15) × 9/5 + 32 = Fahrenheit`.
Since you've added "typescript" as the only tag i presume that you're using Javascript.

```
function kelvinToFahrenheit(kelvin) {
    return (kelvin - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32;
}


kelvinToFahrenheit(380.5); // Will return 225.23
```